# GCC: Restrict long double width

Tags: c++, gcc, long-double

Is there a way/switch to restrict the size of long doubles to 64 bits when compiling using GCC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly [via `-mlong-double-64` command line switch](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html#i386-and-x86-64-Options), but the question is: **why do you want to do that?**

The x86 ABI and [x86-64 System V](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf) ABI mandate a `long double` of 96/80 bits respectively¹, i.e. you need to recompile not only your application, but anything it uses which exposes a long double in the API.

¹ And according to the same doc, GCC on x86-64 uses 128-bit long doubles.

Comment: Page 11 of the [ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi-0.99.pdf) mandates an 80 bit `long double`. There is a separate `__float128` type.

Comment: @BrettHale: oh, interesting that x86 is 96 bits then. I stand corrected. Fixed my reply.

Answer (score -2):

Since typically (read: all platforms that I know of) `double` is 64bit, using long double *explicitely* demands a more-precise floating point number. Thus, there's no way to revert that.

Comment: Both C and C++ only mandate that a `long double` be *at least* `double` precision.

Comment: Yes, but I only *know* platforms where gcc makes long double at least 80b long, because that's what the user indicates he wants.

Comment: Your answer still implies that `long double` is wider than `double`. That's not always true. And since gcc has a `-mlong-double-64` option for some platforms, your answer is factually incorrect (though there are substantial drawbacks to using that option).

Comment: Keith, again I must stress the *typical* and *all platforms **I** know* from my answer. Noone (aside from the cited Bionic C, which seems to be such a special case that the gcc manual cites it!) seems to do that, breaking the ABI.